# Adding django-tagulous to existing model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an existing django model that represents an existing table with a lot of data. I want to add tagging to the model and tagulous  package (http://radiac.net/projects/django-tagulous/ ) seems nice.

When I add tags to my model by adding the kine

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ....
   tags = tagulous.models.TagField()
```

and than running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

one new table is created (`myapp__tagulous_mymodel_tags`) but additional required table is not created (`mymodel_tags`).

When I create new model with tagulous' tag field, both tables are created.

Is it possible to add such field to an existing model?

Comment: Did you add tagulous to INSTALLED_APPS? Maybe that will make it migrate it's tables.

Comment: Yes. I did. 
And it worked with new tables, just not with existing one.